# Sendgrid not sending text to new line

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid api with nodejs and for some reason the emails are sending but not adding new lines.  I've used  and also \n but no luck.  Any idea what is wrong?

Here is the code I am using

```
var email = {
      to: 'test@gmail.com',
      from: 'hello@test.com',
      subject: 'Membership',
      text: 'Please view in html',
      html: 'Hello there!,</br>\n\n' +
      'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
      'Welcome and thanks for joining.\n\n' +
      '</br>Your details we have are\n\n' +
      '</br> Name: ' + user + '\n\n' + '</br> Telephone number: ' + number + '</br> email: ' + email + '</br>'
      };
```

Comment: This is what worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60825296/9669133

Comment: @ServerSideSkittles why don't you mark the solution as accepted answer? I'm sure there must be at least one solution which worked for you. Isn't it?

Answer (score 43):

I assume your "Plain Content" setting is turn off in sendgrid account.
To allow html tags to work you need to use triple curly braces

```
{{{TEMPLATE_VARIABLE}}}
```

It will parse html tag as html rather than plain text. If you'll use double curly braces

```
{{TEMPLATE_VARIABLE}}
```

it will consider any html tag as plain text only.

Comment: Just remember that after you click the save button in Sendgrid it seems to take up to 5 mins sometimes for the changes to take affect. Was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 25):

In places of `</br>` and `\n` Use `<br>`

Comment: I was getting this issue in C# with SendGrid. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

So what worked for me was literally all the answers above combined
@shikhar bansal + @Vipul Patil + EddieB

- Use `<br>` as apposed to a `\n`
- In your sendgrid template (if you're using one), use {{{myVariable}}} instead of just two braces {{myVariable}}. This will let sendgrid know, the variable contains html - So that means your `<br>` will now work.
- Disable plain text by logging into the Sendgrid account. Then go to your template (again, if you have one). if you don't have one, just follow @EddieB answer. Once you have your template in edit mode you'll see two tabs named "Design" and "Preview". Click on "Preview" then select the "Plain Text" tab. Make sure you "Automatically create plain text version" is turned **OFF** then you're good to go.

GOOD LUCK & Happy Emailing!

Answer (score 6):

Sendgrid will automatically convert plain/text email to HTML format. Disable this by logging into the Sendgrid account and going to Settings > Mail Settings and turning ON "Plain Content"... Turn **on** if you **don't** want to convert your plain text email to HTML

Comment: This has now been deprecated by SendGrid due to poor customer take-up of the feature. See [Underused Mail Setting Retirement](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/retired-mail-settings/).